# TRIGGERS in VITESS -> Distributed MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, distributed, vitess, vitess.io

I'm trying to create TRIGGERS in [vitess.io](https://vitess.io) Database. (Distributed MySQL)

I got the following errors :

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_guid BEFORE INSERT ON trx FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.sign = UUID();
MySQL a retourné : vtgate: http:/xxxxxx:15000/: syntax error at position 27 near 'insert_guid'
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: What version of mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply these directly to the mysql.

Comment: How ? Could you please develop your thoughts N

Comment: Sugu Sougoumarane, I tried to even build my vitess from opensource on GKE as I was using it on Planetscale.

Would be keen to help me find the way to define triggers. It is really blocking us in our progress.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Looks like you're using the operator, which doesn't let you access mysql directly. You can try issuing the DDL using vtctlclient ExecuteFetchAsDba command.